# Client side encryption

Tags: java, gwt

i m using java,gwt.while login or creating account when user will enter the password,on server side i m encrypting it but i also want to apply encryption to passord on client side.which i will decrypt on server side and will use it for further process.
i googled but i m not getting which technique should i use for encryption on client side.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why aren't you using HTTPS? That way all your data will be encrypted.

Comment: @peter knego Thanks for your suggession sir.will go through it.and will try it.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Client side encryption in javascript will not be secure because you must somehow provide the key to the client and server. So key will need to be sent over unencrypted network.

This scheme is really a [security through obscurity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity) and is not secure, because someone could reverse engineer your protocol and get the key.

The only way to secure data on the web is [HTTPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Https). You can simply configure this on the server without changing your code.

Answer (score 0):

[GWT-Crypto](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-crypto/) is what you need.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You should understand that this is not really secure, because key is also sent to the client vie unencrypted link: http://code.google.com/p/gwt-crypto/wiki/ClientSideEncryptionConsiderations

Comment: @peter knego actually sir on serverside i m already storing password in encrypted form but when user will enter password ,i want to send that password to server in encrypted form.Any suggestions sir..?

Comment: HTTPS is only truly secure way. Just configure your server - no need to change the code.